# Does a channel have a unique identifier

Tags: go, channel

I have a driver routine with a a dedicated channel to four (or more) different goroutines - the channels all are of the same type -

Does a Go channel have a unique identifier or a way to uniquely identify one channel from another channel, or is the only way to identify the channel is at the time it is created?

Comment: Channel values are comparable. Two channel values are equal if they were created by the same call to `make` or if both have value `nil`. Is this enough for you?

Comment: To add a little detail: they are four (or more) different make calls that are stored in a []struct - i then make a call from the channel stored in the struct - i am trying to figure out as i iterate through them if i can determine if they are different - i am trying to use this for debugging some issues i am having.

Comment: As icza said, you can compare two channel values with `==`, which will be `true` if they're the same channel.

Comment: That actually helps, but it is a slightly different question: Does the internals of a channel have a unique id, or a way to uniquely identify a channel that can be access programmatically?

Comment: You identify the channel by the value, which is stored and accesses wherever you like. How else do you intend to access it programmatically?

Comment: The value in which it is stored, but if it is stored in a []connections it would be nice to be able to look at the details of the connection and have a unique identifier, but there may not be one which is why i asked:

w.connection = make(chan string, 10)

w.connection.(Identifier) or anything that can help track the connections - 

or this may be something that is not available as of yet, which is why i was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a channel have a unique identifier [?]

No.

Comment: Thank you - that is what I thought but before trying for workarounds and lots of spurious  code i needed to ask.